# C++ pass map into qml to determine visibility of items

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qml

I am running a QT 4.8 application. I want to be able to pass a map into qml to determine the visibility of some text items.

QQMLPropertyMap allows for this, but I cannot use with 4.8. Is there anything similar I can do?

Here is sort of what I am going for:

C++

```
map <String, bool> // some type of map to determine visibility
map.insert("key1", true); // insert key/pair values
map.insert("key2", false);
```

QML

```
Text {
    text: "key1"
    visible: map.key1
}
Text {
    text: "key2"
    visible: map.key2
}
```

Also, whenever a map value is changed, I would want the visibility to change in qml. Ex. map.insert("key1" false), now "key1" would not be visible.

Is there anything in QT 4.8 similar to this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`QDeclarativePropertyMap`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdeclarativepropertymap.html) from `QtDeclarative` module. The QDeclarativePropertyMap class allows you to set key-value pairs that can be used in QML bindings.

QtDeclarative module has been [deprecated](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-porting-qt5.html) in Qt 5. All classes that were previously in the QtDeclarative module have been moved into the Qt QML and Qt Quick modules, and their class names have been changed to reflect their new module locations.

> QDeclarativePropertyMap -> QQmlPropertyMap

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to access the map through a public getter as opposed to setting the context property?

Comment: At least you could wrap your map into a QObject and expose each field of the map as a property of that object.